# Customizing liferay hook custom fields

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6, custom-fields

I need to add a `Custom Field` to Site create page, i went to `Portal > Custom Fields > Site` and added a custom field named "`licence`".

I followed this tutorial http://www.liferay.com/pt/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Custom+Fields+and+JSP+Hooks

I'm trying to access this field in `details.jsp` page. It's located at of tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\ROOT\html\portlet\sites_admin\site i tryed to do this:

```
<liferay-ui:custom-attribute
        label="Licence"
        className="<%= Site.class.getName() %>"
        classPK="<%= 0 %>"
        editable="<%= true %>"
        name="licence"
    />
```

but it's wrong. How can I access the Site custom field that i added??

Thanks!!

**Update**
I solved like this

```
    <liferay-ui:custom-attribute        
    className="<%= Group.class.getName() %>"
    classPK="<%= (liveGroup != null) ? liveGroup.getGroupId() : 0 %>"
    editable="<%= true %>"
    label="<%= true %>"
    name="tipo-licenca"
/>
```

Comment: What is wrong in it? Is it not working or gives any exception? Please provide more detail on the output.

Comment: provide groupId of Site for classPK field,

Comment: I resolved the problem, @FelixChristy It was not working, I was using the wrong className.

Comment: @PankajKathiriya, tks for the tip.