# Enabling editting on specific custom fields in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6.2

I am adding some custom fields to the **"user" model of liferay (6.2)**.

As per my use-case I need to show all the fields to all the users, but enable editing on a few of them, other remains read-only.

I read about the "view" permission and "update" permission but former makes all read-only and later makes all editable.

Do I need to create a hook for this or can there be any other solution?

Read this too:
[Customizing liferay hook custom fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168713/customizing-liferay-hook-custom-fields)

Thanks!
AJ

Comment: works for me. You might want to give more detailed steps as to what you're doing, what you see and what you expect to see (and where they differ)

Comment: Thanks @OlafKock, I have not started implementing this, but was studying/researching for a better idea or approach. 

I shortlisted hooking my-account (add a custom jsp) and  implement a custom code to call "liferay-ui:custom-attribute" tag lib and handle editing with a set of permissions.

Comment: Well, each individual custom field has its own permissions. From your description I don't see why there's a call for any custom implementation. If there was, you'd need to go into a lot more detail, posting code samples, to make this question a fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks @OlafKock, I am not sure why I overlooked per "custom fields permission" part, which was exactly what I was look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a set of permissions for each custom field which can be tweaked based on roles, which is what I was looking for.

I overlooked and rightly answered/pointed by @OlafKock.